# How do I add a custom package to debian repository?

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I run my own debian apt repository server. I have a .deb file that i would like to add into the repository (Adaptec Storage Manager deb). I need the ability to manage that package independent of the rest of the repo.

Question:

How can I add the .deb file to the repo so that I can do a 'apt-get storman' on the client machines and have it installed?

Comment: It depends what repository you are using (check the man page) but with reprepo it should be something like `reprepo -b . include $CODENAME $CHANGES`

Comment: and even without a changes file, reprepo can add/remove single .deb archives

Comment: Perhaps you should be setting up your own repo for locally created packages, if only to segregate them from the official ones.

Comment: Do you mean you're currently running a mirror? If it's not a mirror, where are the packages in your existing repository coming from and how do you manage them?

Comment: Yes, we are running am mirror.

Comment: I side with @vonbrand, use a separate repo for packages not in the repo you mirror from, segregation is, imho, much more manageable and the overhead minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a separate repo for your local packages. It just makes sense, as observed by vonbrand and thecarpy.